# Explanation needed regarding return value of: "for comprehension in scala with recursive call"

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, for-comprehension

I am using a for comprehension with a recursive call to generate all posible combinations from an Input List of Int's.

I have a problem understanding the rules on how the output is created.

```
val list = List (1,2,3,4)
def isTrue(l:List[Int],y:List[Int],x:Int):Boolean={

    println("list: "+l)
    println("y :   "+y)
    println("x:    "+x)

    true
}

def allcombos(list: List[Int]):List[List[Int]]= {

    if (list.tail.isEmpty) List(List())
    else for {
              y <- allcombos(list.tail)
              x <- list


              if (isTrue(list,y, x))

    } yield x :: y
}
allcombos(list)
```

The print stmt produces the following output:

```
list: List(3, 4)
y :   List()
x:    3
list: List(3, 4)
y :   List()
x:    4
list: List(2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3)
x:    2
list: List(2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3)
x:    3
list: List(2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3)
x:    4
list: List(2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4)
x:    2
list: List(2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4)
x:    3
list: List(2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4)
x:    4
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 3)
x:    1
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 3)
x:    2
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 3)
x:    3
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 3)
x:    4
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 3)
x:    1
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 3)
x:    2
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 3)
x:    3
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 3)
x:    4
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 3)
x:    1
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 3)
x:    2
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 3)
x:    3
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 3)
x:    4
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 4)
x:    1
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 4)
x:    2
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 4)
x:    3
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(2, 4)
x:    4
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 4)
x:    1
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 4)
x:    2
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 4)
x:    3
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(3, 4)
x:    4
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 4)
x:    1
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 4)
x:    2
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 4)
x:    3
list: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
y :   List(4, 4)
x:    4
```

I don't understand why the value of y is always in the form of List(Int,Int) and never of the form List(Int,Int,Int). I thought this part of the code

```
y <- allcombos(list.tail)
```

would generate as well values for y of the form List(Int,Int,Int) as the 
tail of the input list is of the same form.

If someone could explain me exactly why  I only get values for y of the form List(Int,Int) for y and what I have to change to get values for y of the form List(Int,Int,Int)

this is the solution I want to have:

```
// all orders of a list by rotation
def allOrders[A](list: List[A] ):List[List[A]]=

    (for {
     y <- 0 until list.length
       z = list.drop(y) ::: list.take(y)

 }yield z).toList



def builder[A](list: List[List[A]]):List[List[A]]= {

    def spliter [A](list :List[A]):List[List[A]]={
        val x = builder(allOrders(list.tail))
        val y = list.head
        for {c <- x
             }yield y::c
    }


    def loop[A](list: List[List[A]]):List[List[A]]={
        if(list.isEmpty)List[List[A]]()
        else spliter(list.head):::loop(list.tail)

    }



    list:::loop(list)
}


val allCombos = builder(allOrders(list)).toSet
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand exactly what is the question.

Comment: I asked if someone can explain me why the value for y is always in form List(Int,Int) in the above ouput. Which part of the question do you not understand @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with _"form List(Int, Int)"_. That has two elements? That is not true. - But anyways, let me try to explain the algorithm, bear with me English is not my native language. What the algorithm does is compute all combinations of a List, as such it returns a **List of Lists** _(meaning all the possible lists created from combining the input list)_. The logic is simple, first the base step, all the combinations of the empty list, is just the empty list itself, thus `List(Nil)`...

Comment: Recursive step, is create all the combinations of the tail of the current list. And then, combine all of them with all the elements of the current list... I am not sure if this really helps, but when I explains the problem to my students, I use a table of truth, create yourself a table of truth for three variables: `(T, T, T), (T, T, F), (T, F, T), ..., (F, F, T), (F, F, F)` and then, try to think how would you write a program to print the table given the size. You can hard code the logic for size 1 or 0, then for greater sizes is `(T & F)` combined with all the combinations of the recursion.

Comment: Oh, I just see what is your problem. You have an error in the base step. Try to call the function with and empty list and with a list of just one element.

Comment: I'm not sure what your program is doing, although I am still studying it. I would like to suggest, however, that if you are trying to generate combinations to use Set. For set, order does not matter, which is what you want for combinations. For permutations, you can use List.

Comment: To echo Luis, you base case should be if (list.tail.isEmpty) List(List(list.head)). You need to put the head of your list into the list.

Comment: The design of your algorithm does not seem correct to me. Your output does not generate either combinations or permutations. Which one do you want? Combinations or permutations? Or both?

Comment: You can also try if (list.isEmpty) List(List()). That generates Lists of length three in your lists of lists, but the problem is that this doesn't generate all combinations or permutations either.

Comment: @user6337 thanks for your hint. I wanted to create all possible combinations  of a list without permutation each element should only exist once in the outcomes if it existed only once in the input list. I added my solution to the first version of my code.